# Android - Getting intent extras from previous activity start, not actual one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

my problem is the following:

I have two activities ("A" and "B") which are started from other activities ("launcher activities"). These Launcher activities are launchMode="singleInstance" (dont know if it is important).

A and B receive one parameter through intent extras, which is obtained inside onCreate and onResume methods.

The problem is that if i go from A to a Launcher activity pressing back key, when i come again to A it takes the parameter in the intent perfectly. But if i go through a button to a Launcher activity (not pressing back) and come again to A through a new intent, A doesn't gets the value from the new intent, it remains with the old one. It passes through onResume, but the parameter is not refreshed.

i know it's a bit weird. If you need more info just ask ok? thanks in advance ;)

Here is some of the code:

-- way i get the extras from intent onCreate and onResume in A and B:

```
eventId = getIntent().getLongExtra("eventId", 0);
```

-- way i call A and B from "launcher" activities:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, EventActivity.class);
i.putExtra("eventId", eventId);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: ok here your are @MathanG some code posted, maybe you need some more but i think this is the important part, whole activities codes are too long to post here, and kind of private also, sorry :(

Comment: atleast post oncreate method of both activity and onclick method of button.